# Is there a faster way to empty a HTML Select box?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, select

I have an HTML Select box with about 1800+ options.  In my javascript I have the following line to empty the select box so I can repopulate it.

```
box.options.length = 0;
```

In Firefox this runs fairly quickly, but IE takes a couple of seconds.  Is there a faster way to do this in IE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `box.innerHTML=""`. In my test, it is 68% faster:

http://jsperf.com/emptying-a-select-box/4.

*Update:* in **2015** `box.innerHTML = ""` is by multiple orders of magnitude the slowest option. :-) Use `box.options.length = 0` instead.

Comment: These are all great answers which helped me a lot.  I've given you the tick because this is the closest to what I've ended up doing.  Using the jQuery `$(box).html('')` is even better performance.

Comment: @Kay How did you make the test?

Answer (score 8):

At some point I have worked around IE's dismal performance in this area by enclosing list object in a div and then when I needed to reset it I would just set innerHTML of that div to a brand new empty list html tag.  I'm sketchy on the details but I think that's what I did and it worked.
Please don't tell anybody I suggested this to you.

Comment: Similar experience here. One downside I recall, is that the events bound to the original select are gone once the new one replaces it.

Comment: Use event delegation ( .live() makes it simple if you're using jQuery ) instead of binding directly to an element and you wont have that issue Roland.

Comment: @MK +1 but don't tell anyone i did ;). Alternatively just setting the innerHtml of the `<select>` should work just as quickly without the need for a containing `<div>`

Comment: @James I actually looked up my code and it has some angry comment there about IE failing even at that and having to recreate the whole thing, not just its contents.  And then it also seems to cache it's vertical size and restore it after the update.  I'll go cry now.

Comment: @MK i know your pain. I think i've had a similar problem and the solution is after setting the innerHTML you request the offsetHeight of the object which makes it re-render... there are a few nasty hacks for the height problem. ** hands tissue to MK **

Answer (score 6):

One way that should be faster is to create a new select box with the same properties (but no options, of course), and replace the existing box with it.